# table2excel: Excel file is download but not open in msoffice

Tags: jquery

I written following code to download a table in excel. It is downloaded but in ms-office that file is not open. Please check an error in attached screenshot. Please guide me about the problem.[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>jQuery Boilerplate</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/unconditional/jquery-table2excel/master/src/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table class="table2excel" data-tableName="Test Table 2">
   <thead>
    <tr class="noExl"><td>This shouldn't get exported</td><td>This shouldn't get exported either</td></tr>
    <tr><td>This Should get exported as a header</td><td>This should too</td></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>data1a</td><td>data1b</td></tr>
    <tr><td>data2a</td><td>data2b</td></tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="2">This footer spans 2 cells</td></tr>
   </tfoot>
  </table>
  <button class="exportToExcel">Export to XLS</button>

  <script>
   $.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
    $(".exportToExcel").click(function(e){
     var table = $(this).prev('.table2excel');
     if(table && table.length){
      var preserveColors = (table.hasClass('table2excel_with_colors') ? true : false);
      $(table).table2excel({
       exclude: ".noExl",
       name: "Excel Document Name",
       filename: "myFileName",
       fileext: ".xls"
      });
     }
    });
   });
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note: I've use a theme for admin in project so that i've upload jquery version 3.3.1 and 2.1.4. And because of that table2excel is not working so that i've use noConflict() function.

Comment: Can you confirm it works if you *don't* add the second jquery include?

Comment: *edit* or even the *third* jquery - you have 3 jquery includes (but removing the extras still doesn't seem to get it to work - don't think it has anything to do with that)

Comment: I've comment to second jquery but it is not working. another jquery i've use for sidebar menu and some other function of project. Can you please tell me without comment that jquery how it can work

Comment: No idea - tried to get your table2excel to work with just a very basic page, but it always generated bad html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i checked and found after updating

> jquery.table2excel.js

file its worked fine.
you can download table to excel  [from here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html) 
once completed just replace your jquery.table2excel.js  with downloaded file.
hope its work.

Comment: sir I have download code from above link normally it's working but in a project I've use theme for design. For this design theme I've upload jquery version 3.3.1 and 2.1.4 because of this it is not working. So how could I download excel file with this 2 jquery file. Please check my coding.

Comment: yes i have used your complete code only and its working fine

Comment: yes I've check this now it's work properly. Thank you so much